# Compile PyTorch with additional linker options

Tags: python, cmake, pytorch

I have a modified version of the gloo library. I am able to compile and run programs that use this library (similar to what you can find in `gloo/gloo/examples`).

Now, I want to build pytorch with my library.
I replaced the `third_party/gloo` folder in PyTorch with my version of gloo and I am trying to compile it.

However, my version of gloo requires some additional libraries and special linker options. **Where should these linker options be added in the pytorch build system?**

Without these linker options, my compilation stops with the linker error:

```
/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2_gpu.so: undefined reference to <my code>
/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to <my code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional linker options should be added to:

- the `Caffe2_DEPENDENCY_LIBS` variable in `pytorch/caffe2/CMakeLists.txt` with the command:
  `list(APPEND Caffe2_DEPENDENCY_LIBS <linker_options>)`
- the `C10D_LIBS` variable in `pytorch/torch/lib/c10d/CMakeLists.txt` with the command:
  `list(APPEND C10D_LIBS <linker_options>)`

The additional libraries should have Position Independent Code (they must be compiled with the `-fPIC` flag).